Alt code produces different character on Lenovo laptop (Windows)
Usually on Windows machines, I've been using the Alt code Alt + 158 to insert the multiplication symbol (×). However, on my new Lenovo laptop (also running Windows), the same key combination produces a different character: ₧.
I want to know the reason why that is happening, as I am confused because I am using the same keyboard, same language, same keyboard distribution, latest version of OS and the only thing that changed is that my Lenovo laptop has an Intel 11th CPU and my main PC is using Ryzen. And in case it's possible how can I fix it.
I've tried adding EnableHexNumpad on regedit in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method and restarting my PC, but it didn't work.

Although Windows 11 displayed a specific language, it wasn't actually using it internally. To fix this, I had to go to Control Panel, then Region, Administrative, and Change system locale.
There, the system locale was set to English. On my other Windows PCs, it is set to Spanish. After changing the locale to Spanish, the ALT code worked correctly, just like on my other devices.
As shown in the Wikipedia article on Alt codes:

A common choice in locales using variants of the Latin alphabet was CP850, which provided more Latin character variants.

The table indicates that Alt + 158 with CP850 generates a ×, while normally it would generate ₧.
